# Type mismatch: cannot convert from Set<Object> to Set<Long>

Tags: java, eclipse

I have this code

```
Set<Long> families = humans
            .stream()
            .flatMap(x -> x.data.stream().map(l -> l.person.id))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

with `humans = List<Human>`:

```
public static class Human
{
    public List<Data> data = Lists.newArrayList();
}    

public static class Data
{
    public Person person;
}

public class Person
{
   public long id;
   public String name; 
}
```

This code won't work because of this error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Set to Set
>   Why do I have this error? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry... I edited my question.

Comment: That works fine for me (assuming `Item` is `Person`).

Comment: Really? Do you think it could be Eclipse that is causing this error? I have Luna 4.4.2.

Comment: It _might_ be, but that's pretty basic inference. What happens when you use `javac`?

Comment: Doesn't work with `javac`.

Comment: Try with `.<Long> flatMap(x -> x.data.stream().map(l -> l.person.id))`. Eclipse Luna is known to have issues with inference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why I get the error, but as workarounds:

```
Set<Long> families = humans
            .stream()
            .flatMap(x -> x.data.stream().map(l -> l.person.id)).map(f->(Long) f)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Or (thanks to @Tunaki):

```
Set<Long> families = humans
                .stream()
                .<Long>flatMap(x -> x.data.stream().map(l -> l.person.id))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Or I could just use loops, il's faster than using streams in this case.

Comment: Wouldn't `.stream<Long>().flatmap` be a more correct way?

Comment: Why would it be more correct? I tried it and I had a syntax error.